# Coloring rows in a TreeViewer

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, plugins, jface

How to color rows in a TreeViewer?

It seems there have been a couple of changes since the previous version, now we are migrating to Eclipse 3.4.

It would be great if you can provide a code sample or point me to an open-source project that does this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35467227/1582089

Answer (score 1):

You can use ColumnLabelProvider with overriden `getBackground` method:

```
TreeViewerColumn column = new TreeViewerColumn(treeViewer, SWT.NONE);
column.getColumn().setText("Column name");
column.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
    @Override
    public String getText(Object element) {
        return element.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Color getBackground(Object element) {
        return new Color(Display.getCurrent(), 0, 255, 0);
    }
});
```